# Appended Link does not work when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, bind

I am having a problem with a link that is appended to the page when a new message is available. It acts like a link when hovered over but fails to fire when clicked.

```
var data_split=data.split("*^*");
var count=$('.n_1').length;

if(parseInt(count)!=parseInt(data)) {
    var new_messages=parseInt(data)-parseInt(count);    
    if(new_messages!=0) {
        $('.message_update_holder').html(
            "<p><a class='center n_message' href='javascript:void(0);'>"
            +new_messages+" new notifications.</a></p>");
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

To fire the click event my code is as follows

```
$(document).on('click', '.n_message', function(){
    get_notifications();
});
```

It should be noted that the first part of the code is loacted in a function that updates every 10 seconds. I have tried clearing the html from message_update_holder on every update but this did not seem to work.

Comment: jsfiddle to demonstrate the behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
 href='javascript:void(0);'
```

Into this:

```
href='#something'
```

Because I think that javascript call would cause the disfunctionality.

Comment: This seems to be working so far although previously I tries href="#" which did not. I will keep working in hope your answer is correct - so far so good - many thanks

Comment: Actually - started doing the same thing again :(

Comment: Maybe you can post the whole code @ http://jsfiddle.net/ ? We could check the whole code and can work on a working example. Which webbrowser are you using? And which version?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.n_message').live('click', function(){
    get_notifications();
});
```

Ca you try same with `live`

Comment: Another one with the deprecated live() function?

Comment: Thanks - but tried this. The only thing I can think is that everytime there is an update it binds another anchor ref onto the object but I am not 100% about using the bind object in jquery as yet